# Find and replace a string after a special character using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file containing URLs with unique parameters, with some URLs having multiple parameters. I am trying to replace all characters *after* the `=` to something else.

**Example URL in `file-containing-urls.txt`:**

```
https://somewebsite.com/some/path/?parameter=value&another=somethingelse
```

**Example `sed` command:**

```
sed -r '/^\=/!s/=.*$/=somevalue/g' file-containing-urls.txt
```

Though this works, it's only replacing the first parameter and nothing else. I would like **all** characters after an `=` to be a specific string. Here is my result:

```
https://somewebsite.com/somepath/?param=mystring  --> Works
https://somewebsite.com/new/path/?param1=mystring&param2=removed  --> Only works for param1
```

The second example, I would like my string to also carry over to `param2`, but it looks like `sed` is only replacing the first value and ignoring the rest. All other parameters are getting removed from the view. I thought a `/g` would fix this, but I'm always getting the same result. Thank you!

Comment: `.*$` greedily consumes everything to the end of the line, so there's nothing left for `/g` to repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/=[^=&]*/=somevalue/g' file
https://somewebsite.com/some/path/?parameter=somevalue&another=somevalue
```